# Replacing a specific column of a file with the column of another file using sed in linux

Tags: linux, replace, sed

I have two files.

file1 has the data like belowing containing only one column.

```
112.319
108.915
105.512
```

file2 has the data like belowing containing eight columns.

```
0.000000     0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000         0     0.0001.0000E+20  
0.000000     0.000     0.000     0.000 20.000000         0     0.0001.0000E+20  
0.000000     0.000     0.000     0.000 20.000000         0     0.0001.0000E+20
```

I want to replace the first column of file2 with the first column of file1 and the output would be

```
112.319     0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000         0     0.0001.0000E+20  
108.915     0.000     0.000     0.000 20.000000         0     0.0001.0000E+20  
105.512     0.000     0.000     0.000 20.000000         0     0.0001.0000E+20
```

I tried to replace the first record of each line with the first record of other line but was not successful. I would be thankful if somebody can help me doing is using  sed.

best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
join -o 1.2,2.3,2.4,2.5,2.6,2.7,2.8 <(cat -n file1) <(cat -n file2) | column -t
```

produces

```
112.319  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000      0  0.0001.0000E+20
108.915  0.000  0.000  0.000  20.000000  0  0.0001.0000E+20
105.512  0.000  0.000  0.000  20.000000  0  0.0001.0000E+20
```

---

Update: since the whitespace is significant, you can use string replacements. Here's awk:

```
awk 'NR==FNR {n[FNR]=$1; next} {sub(/[^[:space:]]+/, n[FNR]); print}' f1 f2
```

producing

```
112.319     0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000         0     0.0001.0000E+20
108.915     0.000     0.000     0.000 20.000000         0     0.0001.0000E+20
105.512     0.000     0.000     0.000 20.000000         0     0.0001.0000E+20
```

Comment: it works but changes the format, like the spacing between the numbers is very important othwise the software dont recognize the numbers.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `paste`/`tr`/`cut`/`column` commands:

```
$ paste file{1,2} | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 1,3- | column -t
112.319  0.000000  0.000  0.000  0.000      0  0.0001.0000E+20
108.915  0.000000  0.000  0.000  20.000000  0  0.0001.0000E+20
105.512  0.000000  0.000  0.000  20.000000  0  0.0001.0000E+20
```

Comment: it is not working at all.  file1 has a name Reibung.txt and file2 has a name of friction.txt so I wrote                             paste Reibung.txt friction.txt | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 1,3- | column -t  > friction1     #  but nothing happened.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
 cut -d' ' -f2- file2 | paste -d' ' file1 -
```

or this (GNU sed):

```
sed 'R file2' file1 | sed 'N;s/\n\S*//'
```

or this:

```
 awk 'FNR==NR{a[NR]=$1;next};{sub($1,a[FNR])}1' file1 file2
```

EDIT:

This might work for you:(GNU sed?)

```
sed '=;s/.*/s|\\S*|&|/' file1 | sed 'N;s/\n//' | sed -i -f - file2
```

Comment: your solution is near to the one I am looking for.   with sed this works ok but the problem is that it add the column to the file 2 but dont replace there. I mean it copy but donot replace. I am looking forwards to the solution with sed, regards

Comment: I think you mean you want to use the `-i` edit in place feature. See EDIT.